# How to find if URL contains specific format and then run execute current transcation

Tags: if-statement, jmeter

I currently have two transaction controllers in `JMeter`. I'd like to execute the first transaction if `${url}` contains -1 at the end and the second transactions if `${url}` does not contain -1 at the end.

`${url}` is variable which comes from CSV data set config. Basically it's a regular HTTP URL.

This is how my `JMeter` test plan looks like:

```
Thread Group
--CSV Data Set config 
--Transaction 1
  --HTTP request which will execute ${URL} 
-- Transaction 2
  ----HTTP request which will execute ${URL}
```

Now I can add `If` above each Transaction but I am not sure what I should compare the `If` statement with.

Sample URL:

First URL - /test/user/editprofile/userid/1234 -1
Second URL - /test/user/viewprofile/userid/8975

The first URL should run under first transactions and the second URL should run under second transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the if controller you can put the following as the condition:

```
"${__BeanShell('${URL}'.contains('-1'))}"
```

The children of the if controller will be executed if the url contians -1.
You would then need a second if controller with:

```
"${__BeanShell(!'${URL}'.contains('-1'))}"
```

for the second request.

Another option would be to use a switch controller with the first request as the first child and the second as the second child.  Then in a post processor  you would need to set a variable to 0 or 1 depending on the  result.

```
var url = vars.get('URL');
var switch = 0;
if(!url.contains('-1'))
     switch = 1;

vars.put('switch', switch.toString());
```

Use ${switch} as the condition variable in the switch controller.

Comment: There is no "contains" function in JavaScript as far as I'm aware

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.  Switch controller logic will work? I will give it try on Sunday and will share the result. Meanwhile if you have any other suggestions, kindly suggest

Comment: @DmitriT You are correct, thanks.  I edited the answer to use the BeanShell function, which was what I intended, I had js on the brain earlier.  I have tested this solution.

Comment: @user1169236 I use switch controllers all the time.  The key is that with the switch controller you need to make sure the children are in the correct order, relevant to their conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Build you Test Plan as follows:

- Thread Group

  - CSV Data Set Config
  - If Controller - condition `"${URL}".indexOf("-1") > -1`

    - Sampler to be executed if URL contains "-1"
  - If Controller - condition `"${URL}".indexOf("-1") == -1`

    - Sampler to be executed if URL does NOT contain "-1"

See [How to use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) guide for more details on using JMeter's [IF Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) to run samplers basing on certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks both of you, i have tried above solutions and it worked. But Switch controller seems to be not working.